# MockMvc Test does not get to the endpoint for a Multipart file in a RestController

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-rest

I am calling a service in an orders controller which receives a multipart file and processes it and saving it into a database.  I am trying to create a Spring Rest Doc for it but it is not even hitting the endpoint. I am creating a list of orders which is what the service expects. It receives the order as a stream as shown and converts into a stream of orders before saving it into a database. I have shown the main part of the controller and my code for generating the rest docs. When I run the code I get the following exception, it never even hits the endpoint when I set a breakpoint. I also used fileupload() but that did not work either.

Exception is:

Content type = application/json
             Body = {"path":"/orders/order_reception","exceptionName":
"MissingServletRequestPartException","message":"Required request part 'uploadFile' is not

present",
"rootExceptionName":"MissingServletRequestPartException",
"rootMessage":"MissingServletRequestPartException: Required request part 'uploadFile' is not present"}

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/orders")
@Validated
class OrderController{

@PostMapping(path = "/order_reception")

public ResponseEntity receiveData(@RequestPart MultipartFile uploadFile,
                                               HttpServletRequest request,
                                               HttpServletResponse response) {
    if (!uploadFile.isEmpty()) {
        try {
            Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream()));
            ... save file

            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.HttpStatus.CREATED);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
    return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}




@Test
 public void sendData() throws Exception {

     ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

     Order order = repository.getOrder("1233333");

     List<Order> orderList = new ArrayList<>():

     resourceList.add(order);

     MockMultipartFile orderFile = new MockMultipartFile("order-data", "order.json", "application/json", 

     mapper.writeValueAsString(orderList).getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset()));

     mockMvc.perform(multipart("/orders/order_reception")
             .file(orderFile))
             .andExpect(status().isCreated())
             .andDo(document("send-order",
                     preprocessRequest(prettyPrint()),
                     preprocessResponse(prettyPrint())));
 }
```

Comment: The code shown here doesn't match your exception nor would it even compile. But in your test your multipart element is named `order-data` not `file` as stated by the error message.

Comment: I only added the portions not including the imports as it would be too long. I do not use any identifier called file.

Comment: You use that identifier based on the exception (unless that isn't the exception) and the code uses the same method argument twice which makes it invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Marten Deinum, your suggestion that the file name was wrong fixed it.
I simply changed name in the MockMultipartFile( "uploadsFile", ...)